# Characterisation of the subdifferential of a $\lambda$-convex function.

Tags: convex-analysis, subgradient

If $F$ is convex, then the inequality that characterizes the subgradient is $$F(y)\ge F(x)+\langle p,y-x\rangle$$ and if F is $\lambda$-convex (i.e. $F(x)-\frac{\lambda}{2}\|x\|^2$ is convex), the inequality that characterises the subgradients is $$F(y)\ge F(x)+\frac{\lambda}{2}|y-x|^2+\langle p,y-x\rangle.$$ I don't understand how we got the characterization for the $\lambda$-convex function.

Comment: Both arise as special cases of the Fréchet subdifferential. The Fréchet subdifferential of a functional $\Phi \colon \mathbb R^d \to (- \infty, \infty]$ at $v$ is $$\partial \Phi(v) :=
        \begin{cases}
            \displaystyle \left\{ \xi \in \mathbb R^d: \text{liminf}_{w \to v} \frac{\Phi(w) - \Phi(v) - \xi \cdot (w - v) }{\| w - v \|} \ge 0 \right\},    & \text{if } v \in \text{dom}(\Phi), \\
            \emptyset,                                                                                                              & \text{else.}
        \end{cases}$$

Comment: If $F$ is $\lambda$-convex with $\lambda < 0$, then $F$ might not be convex, so the definition of the subdifferential for convex functions you gave at the beginning of the post can not be applied, so you can't derive the latter from the former in that case. The case $\lambda \ge 0$ is trivial.